# Last row is a blank row in flat file destination SSIS Package

Tags: flat-file, ssis-2008

An SSIS package exporting data to the flat file text. The exporting work fine, except for the blank row at the end of file. Is there a simple way to get rid of the blank row?

Ragged Right in Source and Destination Flat File Connection
9 Columns Defined with Appropriate Input Column Width and Output Column Width.

no header rows and last column delimiter CRLF.

**Source**

[image: SOURCE File]

**Destination**

[image: Destination File]

Thanks in advance.
BV

Answer (score 0):

Conditional Split works perfectly, you dont need to set an action for rows that do not meet the criteria, so they can essentially be ignored.

[SSISPackage with Conditional Split](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GUG4.png)

Answer (score -1):

Use a Conditional Split Transformation in between source and destination to remove empty rows from data flow pipeline. In the Split transformation editor specify boolean SSIS expression in Condition column something like

```
LEN([Col 1]) > 0 && LEN([Col 2]) > 0 ...
```

Or

```
ID != "" && [Col 1] != "" && [Col 2] != ""
```

[**Conditional Split**](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/ssis-basics-using-the-conditional-split/)

Comment: i tried your approach as well. There is still an empty row in the destination file though source file doesn't have any empty rows.

Comment: I don't know why people keep recommending this. Yes, you remove the blank row but then you are saving to a new destination file with CR LF, so the blank row is added back. Balaji, did you ever figure this out?